# How to unwrap an optional list of type Images in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, option-type

I have a global variable
`var list_of_images: [Image]?`that I append to on a button click. When I try to access this from another file, I do

```
ForEach(0..<list_of_images?.count) {
                    list_of_images?[$0]
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
```

But I get the following error:
Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'

I understand that I need to unwrap list_of_images, but I've tried several methods that haven't worked, such as

```
ForEach(0..<list_of_images?.count ?? 0)
```

and more.

How do I go about unwrapping an optional list of images?

Comment: As answered below, the ?? operator works well. I'd also recommend learning "if-let" and "guard" statements as well. [Here's a quick video](https://youtu.be/wmQIl0O9HBY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest direct answer to this is to use the same `??` operator you mentioned to provide an empty array:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var list_of_images : [Image]? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<(list_of_images ?? []).count) {
            list_of_images?[$0]
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd be concerned in general about the idea of storing the `Image`s themselves. I might look into another way of storing references to them (paths? names? UIImages?) that could be iterated over instead. In that case, you could do something like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var imageNames : [String]? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(imageNames ?? [], id: \.self) { imageName in
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}
```

This approach doesn't work with the array of `Image`s because `Image` doesn't conform to `Identifiable`

**Update, based on comments:**

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var images : [UIImage]? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(images ?? [], id: \.self) { image in
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could extract the name of the Image from one that a user selects. Currently when I present the ImagePicker, I have `onDismiss: LoadImage` where LoadImage function is

`guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }` and
`list_of_images?.append(Image(uiImage: inputImage))`

Is there a way to extract the name from inputImage or Image that would allow me to do the latter method you suggested?

Comment: In the case you describe, I'd store an array of `UIImage`s instead of `Image`. I'll update my answer to show this case.

Comment: By the way, another way to handle this is to not have an optional array, but instead just have your default state by an *empty* array.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That's actually perfect. Thank you for the help and the kind explanation!